# How to implement setOnFocusChangeListener for CustomAutoCompleteTextView in Android app

Tags: java, android

```
 actvDivName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
               try{
                   String str = actvDivName.getText().toString();
                   if(b){
                       actvPType.setText("");
                   }

                   else{
                       for (int i=0;i<QRDivArrayAdapter.getCount();i++)
                       {
                           String temp = QRDivArrayAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
                           if (str.compareTo(temp) == 0){
                               return;
                           }
                       }
                       actvDivName.setText("");
                   }
            }catch(Exception focusfordivision)
               {
                   Log.d("eEmp/Resume", "Error raised due to " + focusfordivision.toString());
               }
        }
        });


     actvEntryCategory.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                String str = actvEntryCategory.getText().toString();
                if(b)
                {
                    actvDivName.setText("");
                    actvPType.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i=0;i<EntryTypeAdapter.getCount();i++)
                    {
                        String temp = EntryTypeAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
                        if (str.compareTo(temp) == 0){
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    actvEntryCategory.setText("");
                }

               // actvEntryCategory.setError("Please select valid Entry Type");
            }
        });
```

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LLPlaceDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/zone_card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.54"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_zone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actventry"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="11"
                        android:hint="@string/Entry_Type"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords|textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLength="250"
                        android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Division"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actventryDivName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="@string/station"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords|textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLength="250"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AutocompleteTheme"
                         />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

               <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_ProductType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actvProductType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="@string/product_type"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords|textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLength="250"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_FromDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtFromDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:hint="@string/from_date"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_FromTime"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtFromTime"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:inputType="none"
                            android:hint="@string/from_time"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_toDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtToDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:hint="@string/to_date"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_toTime"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtToTime"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.6"
                            android:inputType="none"
                            android:hint="@string/to_time"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>
```

`actventry`, `actventryDivName`, `actvProductType` are three `CustomAutoCompleteTextViews` in xml file.

the method is working for `actventry` but not working for `actventryDivName` and `actvProductType`.

`actvDivName` and `actvEntryCategory` are `CustomAutoCompleteTextViews`. Likewise I have written this method for remaining one `CustomAutoCompleteTextView` as well.

There are three `CustomAutoCompleteTextView` in my layout, but this method is called for only the first `CustomAutoCompleteTextView`, not for the remaining two.

What mistake did I make? I am new to android.

Comment: what is actvDivName? you should add listeners to each element

Comment: The OnFocusChangeListener seems OK at first glance. Make sure that the initialization of the second and the third CustomAutoCompleteTextView is correct.

Comment: Ahamad Anees I have edited my question. please check @RezoShalikashvili

Comment: post you xml file here.

Comment: I have posted xml file. please check@AliasgarVadivala